# Uploading images

Tags: php, file-upload, file-permissions

I got this error when I'm uploading the image into the folder:

> Warning: fopen(images1/image.jpg) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied.

I gave read/write permissions. but its not working.How to rectify this error? Anyone can help me please?

Regards,
padma.

Comment: How does the corresponding code look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you have read/write permissions to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you don't have the permission to open the image in `images/image.jpg`?

Also, make sure that you have the access right to the folder.